# CSS alignment without tables - why two divs are overlapping if margin unspecified?

Tags: css

In the example below from:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float6

```
<head>
<style>
div.container
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    line-height:150%;
}
div.header,div.footer
{
    padding:0.5em;
    color:white;
    background-color:gray;
    clear:left;
}
h1.header
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div.left
{
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    margin:0;
    padding:1em;
}
div.content
{
    margin-left:190px;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    padding:1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="header"><h1 class="header">W3Schools.com</h1></div>
<div class="left"><p>"Never increase, beyond what is necessary, the number of entities required to explain anything." William of Ockham (1285-1349)</p></div>
<div class="content">
<h2>Free Web Building Tutorials</h2>
<p>At W3Schools you will find all the Web-building tutorials you need,
 from basic HTML and XHTML to advanced XML, XSL, Multimedia and WAP.</p>
<p>W3Schools - The Largest Web Developers Site On The Net!</p></div>
<div class="footer">Copyright 1999-2005 by Refsnes Data.</div>
</div>
```

If I remove margin from div.content, then the border of div.content overlaps with the border of container. That means the div.content overlaps with div.left - though the text in div.content follows that of div.left. Then the question is why is the behavior so? The text is not overlapping but the margin is. If we mention float for a couple of divs then they follow each other without having to mention how much margin apart from the leftmost edge of the, say, page. How to differentiate between the two scenarios?

Thanks a ton for the help in understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have removed  the margin from the content-div the margins of the container and content-div doesn't merge instead the width(not visible) of the left-div is acting as margin for the content-div.
But when the content-div's data increases beyond height specified to left-div then it overflows and take margin from left-div.

Answer (score 0):

Floating wasn't originally meant to be used for layout rendering - it's primary purpose is to wrap text around images (or other elements). This is the behavior you're seeing.

When you float elements they are no longer considered "block" elements and their width "shrink-wraps" to the smallest size possible to contain the elements. That's why when you float multiple elements next to each other, the proceeding elements don't overlap the previous ones.